# Positioning Nodes With `{rank=same ...}` Side Effects

Tags: graphviz

I have a graph defined as such:

```
digraph G {
    rankdir=LR
    node[shape=circle]
    q_[shape=none label=""]
    q3[shape=doublecircle]
    q4[shape=doublecircle]
    q_->q0
    q0->q1[label="λ"]
    q0->q2->q4[label=a]
    q1->q4->q2[label=b]
    q1->q3[label=a]
    q3->q4[label="λ"]
    {rank=same; q4 q3}
    {rank=same; q1 q2}
}
```

The graph outputs the following image:

[image]

You can play with the graph here: http://graph.gafol.net/derive/effpjWfSD

My question is:

Why is q4 pointing to q3 in the rendered graph and not the way I specified it in the markup? Is it because `{rank=same; q4 q3}` has more semantic meaning than just positioning nodes? If that is the case, how can I position the nodes so that the output is not as hideous as the output is without using `{rank=same; ...}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no hidden semantic meaning in `rank=same`, **this is simply a bug**.

The edge is correctly drawn when for example omitting the label of the edge or `rankdir=LR`.

You may correct this particular graph by adding the `dir` attribute to the incorrectly drawn edge:

```
q3->q4[label="λ", dir=back]
```

This is of course of no help when dynamically creating graphs.

This bug may be related to one of the other known bugs caused by `rankdir=LR`, reported on http://www.graphviz.org:8080/bugs/openbugs.html

Comment: Adding `dir=back` as an edge property worked. The correct node is being pointed to. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Changing {rank=same; q4 q3} to {rank=same; q3 q4} may also work (not tested). Reading from top to bottom, left to right, the most recent layout instruction for those nodes (q3 and q4) changes previous lines' ordering and overrides prior arrows:

{rank=same; q4 q3}

Maybe this is not a bug.